# getFlickString (private UIKit method) crash on iOS 7 with Japanese keyboard

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a simple textField that prompts the user to answer in English.
In order to force the keyboard to be displayed in English I set it to TypeURL as follows:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

I keep getting crash reports about getFlickString from users in Japan (all running iOS 7), but I haven't been able to reproduce it myself.
getFlickString seems to be a private UIKit Method.

Any ideas?

Thanks everyone for any help in advance!

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException NSRangeException *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 4] raw
0        CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1        libobjc.A.dylib     objc_exception_throw + 38
2        CoreFoundation  -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 232
3        UIKit   getFlickString + 46
4        UIKit   -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar(UIKeyboardLayoutJapanese50OnFlick) flickStringForInputKey:direction:] + 164
5        UIKit   -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar completeRetestForTouchUp:timestamp:interval:executionContext:] + 2818
6        UIKit   -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar touchUp:executionContext:] + 1474
7        UIKit   -[UIKeyboardLayoutStarAccessibility(SafeCategory) touchUp:executionContext:] + 42
8        UIKit   __28-[UIKeyboardLayout touchUp:]_block_invoke + 224
9        UIKit   -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 352
10       UIKit   -[UIKeyboardLayout touchUp:] + 236
11       UIKit   -[UIKeyboardLayout touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 324
12       UIKit   -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
13       UIKit   -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 832
14       UIKit   -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
15       UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7116
```

Comment: A quick google shows up your question only. You should file a bug report with Apple for this.

Comment: I also received this same crash report. Any updates on this issue?

Comment: I submitted a bug report. No update thus far.

Comment: Same error for me - no idea where it happens :(

Comment: Don't know the exact cause of the crash, but the getFlickString is called for the flick Kana keyboard. example: http://www.iphone-girl.jp/wp-content/tmp/vol/2014/10/IMG_01781re2.jpg The crash may be a result of altering the text length on a change event